# Extra line in haml when formats fine in html

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I created a simple login page using [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/)  in Html.

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Login ionic form</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-    beta.9/css/ionic.css"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
   <h1 class="title">Welcome!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content has-header padding">
    <div class="list list-inset">
     <label class="item item-input">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
     </label>
     <label class="item item-input">
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
     </label>
    </div> 
    <button class="button button-block button-positive">
     Log In
    </button>
     <div class="row" align="center">
     <div class="col col-50"><button class="button button-light">Forgot Pass?     </button></div>
     <div class="col col-50"><button class="button button-light">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign UP&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But when i convert it to HAML and run it with sinatra with thin i get formatting issues. The issue being it cuts off the bottom buttons.
I have no clue where to look or understand why this is happening.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Login ionic form
    %link{href: "http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/css/ionic.css", rel:     "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui", name: "viewport"}/
  %body
    .bar.bar-header.bar-stable
      %h1.title Welcome!
    .content.has-header.padding
      .list.list-inset
        %label.item.item-input
          %input{placeholder: "Username", type: "text"}/
        %label.item.item-input
          %input{placeholder: "Password", type: "password"}/
      %button.button.button-block.button-positive
        Log In
      .row{align: "center"}
        .col.col-50
          %button.button.button-light Forgot Pass?
        .col.col-50
          %button.button.button-light     Sign UP
```

My current "stack" is 
sinatra 
haml

thin-server / have tried both development and production

my server "app"

```
%w[sinatra haml].each{|gem| require gem}

get '/' do 
    haml :index
end
```

HAML
[image: HAML]
HTML
[image: HTML]

HAML pastebin
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=sQ5Pc1YK

HTML pastebin
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=DP4rSx31

Comment: Have you tried the various whitespace control issues, e.g., are the newlines in the button divs pushing you past your height?

Comment: Your Haml version includes the doctype, and it looks like this is what is causing the difference. Try adding `<DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your HTML version and compare. I don’t know Ionic so I can’t tell you why your code renders like this with a doctype. As a workaround you could omit `!!!`  from the Haml version to leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

had to add some style: "padding-top: xxpx; padding-top: xxpx;" in places. I guess something is still broken somewhere. It looks fine and all but I feel robbed because I thought everything would format correctly when i converted from HTML > HAML.

Comment: First, you can check the "source-code" of the resulting html (rendered haml), and diff it (maybe ignore whitespaces, first) against your "original" html. And then, if you actually found a solution post it as answer (as you did) and accept that answer. Also, maybe adjust the answer to include matt and daves comment, if they are relevant. thanks.